# External JSON and External Template - Can't get both to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've just started getting my head around Handlebars.JS and I can see it is a very powerful tool.

I want to be able to use externally loaded templates and externally loaded JSON to keep my code clean and with less duplication across pages.

At the minute I can only get one or the other working, I can load an external template with local JSON data, or load an external JSON file with a local template. But, I would like to do both!

I can't see anything on the handlebars documentation that covers either external JSON or external templates.

Here is the closest I've got so far...

My javascript...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Please work!</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.1.2/handlebars.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>


    <div id="anchor">My stuff should appear here</div>

    <script>

    var jsonData;

    function user_tracker(){ 

        $.getJSON("data/JSON_test.php", function(data) {
            jsonData = JSON.stringify(data); 
        });


        $.ajax({
            url: 'data/templates/test.php', 
            cache: true,
            success: function(data) {
                source    = data;
                template  = Handlebars.compile(source);
                $('#anchor').html(template(jsonData));
            }               
        }); 


    }


    $(document).ready(function($) {
        user_tracker();
    });


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my JSON file...

```
{ "people":
    [
        {
            "family": "Lopez",
            "name": "Hugo",
            "title": "leader",
            "place": "Paris (France)",
            "introduction": "WP:Map workshop's Dino, GIS, Gdal & D3js lightener",
            "photo": "WikiAtlas_Lopez_Hugo_Yug.png",
            "twitter": "http://www.twitter.com/Hugo_lz"
        },        
        {
            "family": "Ganesh",
            "name": "Arun",
            "title": "co-leader",
            "place": "Dharamsala (India)",
            "introduction": "GIS, D3js enthusiast, interactions designers & wikidata tinker",
            "photo": "WikiAtlas_Ganesh_Arun_Planemad.jpg",
            "twitter": "http://www.twitter.com/planemad"
        },
        {
            "family": "Lopez",
            "name": "Edouard",
            "title": "Hero",
            "place": "Bordeaux (France)",
            "introduction": "Backend admin & Frontend professional webdev, scripts & stack consulting",
            "photo": "WikiAtlas_Lopez_Edouard_Lyhana8.png",
            "twitter": "http://wwww.twitter.com/edouard_lopez"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is my template file....

```
<div>
Hey! I've loaded!
{{#people}}
            <div><img src="{{photo}}"><b><a href="{{twitter}}">{{family}} {{name}}</a></b> — {{title}}, {{place}} : {{introduction}}.</div>
{{/people}}
</div>
```

The template loads fine, but it appears the JSON doesn't. I don't get any errors in the console at all.

I added the **JSON.stringify** because I was previously getting an error that Handlebars didn't like an object being passed to it.

Comment: Tried this? `$('#anchor').html(template({people:jsonData}));`

Comment: You should pass the `object`. So you may omit `JSON.stringify`. If your response is in JSON then do `JSON.parse(jsondata)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find the go-to duplicate question, but this is a very common problem in JS, and has to do with the nature of asynchronous execution.

Basically, imagine you need to cook lunch; and you decide to have your two kids help. So you tell Joey to run to the store and get some more potatoes (because you have no potatoes left in the house), and you tell little Jen to bring you the knife from the drawer (because of course she won't cut herself, she's already four!). You decide you'll start chopping as soon as Jen does her errand; but since Joey is not back yet, you finish chopping very, very quickly. Then, your wife complains how there's no actual potatoes in the potato soup. Joey finally comes home, having missed (a very bland) dinner. All of that could have been avoided if you waited for both kids.

Your `jsonData` is your potatoes, the errand you don't wait on. Your template is Jen's knife, the errand which you immediately follow with template compilation.

There are two and a half solutions for this.

- Not great, but easy: Send Jen for the knife only when Joey is back (or vice versa):

  ```
  $.getJSON("data/JSON_test.php", function(jsonData) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'data/templates/test.php', 
        cache: true,
        success: function(source) {
            var template  = Handlebars.compile(source);
            $('#anchor').html(template(jsonData));
        }               
      });
  });
  ```
- The real thing: count that all your kids are present before you start cooking:

  ```
  var ajaxDone = 0;
  var jsonData, template;

  function runTemplate() {
    $('#anchor').html(template(jsonData));
  }

  $.getJSON("data/JSON_test.php", function(data) {
      jsonData = data; 
      if (++ajaxDone == 2) runTemplate();
  });

  $.ajax({
      url: 'data/templates/test.php', 
      cache: true,
      success: function(data) {
          var source    = data;
          template  = Handlebars.compile(source);
          if (++ajaxDone == 2) runTemplate();
      }               
  });
  ```
- Use promises, which will do the counting for you.

  ```
  $.when(
    $.getJSON("data/JSON_test.php"),
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data/templates/test.php', 
        cache: true,
    })
  ).then(function(responseJSON, responseTemplate) {
    // ...
  });
  ```

  (I don't know off the top of my head what `responseJSON` and `responseTemplate` format ends up as, probably something like `[data, statusText, jqXHR]`... so, `console.log` them, see for yourself where's potatoes and where's the knife.)

EDIT: I was blindly copy-pasting, but yeah, you must not `JSON.stringify` here. Lemme quickly strip that.

Comment: Thanks so much Amadan! That worked a treat. Explained very well!

Answer (score 0):

Due to Asynchronous nature of AJAX requests, you may end up trying to use the data before you get. Solution is using `$.Deferred` like this:

```
  <script>

var jsonData;

function user_tracker(){ 

    var jsonData = getJSONData();

    var ajaxData = getAJAXData();


    $.when(ajaxData, jsonData).done(html, json){
        var template  = Handlebars.compile(html);
        $('#anchor').html(template(json);
   }





}

 function getJSONData(){
     var defObj = $.Deferred();
     $.getJSON("data/JSON_test.php", function(data) {
       defObj.resolve(JSON.parse(data)); //parse if response in JSON 
    });
    return defObj.promise();
 }

function getAJAXData(){
  var defObj = $.Deferred();
  $.ajax({
        url: 'data/templates/test.php', 
        cache: true,
        success: function(data) {
            //source    = data;
            //template  = Handlebars.compile(source);
            //$('#anchor').html(template(jsonData));
            defObj.resolve(data);
        }               
    }); 
  return defObj.promise();
}


$(document).ready(function($) {
    user_tracker();
});


</script>
```

See the entire script snippet above

Comment: "passing data to template in a wrong way" - why? `jsonData` already contains `people` attribute. Your way ends up with `{ people: { people: [...] } }`, no?

Comment: A template should be passed an `object` `{key:value}` which then can be iterated in the template

Comment: Inside the template, we can iterate like `{{#key.people}}...{{/if}}`

Comment: `jsonData` *is* an object (as long as the misguided `JSON.stringify` is not there).